# Запись звука с микрофона ноутбука

Tags: python, pyaudio

Пишу комплекс приложений(клиент+сервер+плеер).
Возникает проблема с клиентом, а именно со скриптом, предназначенным для записи звука с микрофона.
На выходе я получаю 1 из 2 ошибок(в зависимости от индекса устройства)
**[Errno -9998] Invalid number of channels
OSError: [Errno -9999] Unanticipated host error**

```
import pyaudio
import wave

chunk = 1024 # Запись кусками по 1024 сэмпла
sample_format = pyaudio.paInt16 # 16 бит на выборку
channels = 2
rate = 44100 # Запись со скоростью 44100 выборок(samples) в секунду
seconds = 3
filename = "output_sound.wav"
p = pyaudio.PyAudio() # Создать интерфейс для PortAudio

print('Recording...')

stream = p.open(format=sample_format,
channels=channels,
rate=rate,
frames_per_buffer=chunk,
input_device_index=2, # индекс устройства с которого будет идти запись звука 
input=True)

frames = [] # Инициализировать массив для хранения кадров

# Хранить данные в блоках в течение 3 секунд
for i in range(0, int(rate / chunk * seconds)):
    data = stream.read(chunk)
    frames.append(data)

# Остановить и закрыть поток
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
# Завершить интерфейс PortAudio
p.terminate()

print('Finished recording!')

# Сохранить записанные данные в виде файла WAV
wf = wave.open(filename, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(channels)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(sample_format))
wf.setframerate(rate)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

Comment: я пробовал уже все 12 устройств , доступных на пк и которые видит библиотека, пробовал корректировку, пробовал настройки самого устройства редачить и прочее
ошибка с каналами - самое частое , что я вижу и если честно, я в тупик зашел

Answer (score 0):

Используйте этот код для определения количества каналов на устройстве:

```py
import pyaudio

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
    dev = p.get_device_info_by_index(i)
    print((i, dev['name'], dev['maxInputChannels']))
```

В результате выводится список состоящий из (ид устройства, имени устройства, максимального количества каналов) если количество каналов 0 то с устройства нельзя записывать звук. Количество каналов подставляете в `channels`.

Если вы используете Windows, то `OSError: [Errno -9999] Unanticipated host error` может быть связана с настройками конфиденциальности попробуйте Параметры -> Конфиденциальность и защита -> Микрофон убедитесь что есть доступ к микрофону и доступ к микрофону у python разрешён (У меня python находится в классических приложениях поэтому нужно просто нажать галочку разрешить классическим приложениям)

Comment: спасибо, увидел, что те девайсы, с которых можно вести запись, имеют 0 каналов
а при указании других я получаю либо OSError: [Errno -9999] Unanticipated host error
либо OSError: [Errno -9996] Invalid device
есть ли какие либо еще варианты?

Comment: @ДмитрийЛитвиненко изменил ответ